# Convert SQL Server varbinary(max) into a set of primary keys of type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinary

**Disclaimer: not my code, not my database design!**

I have a column of `censusblocks(varbinary(max), null)` in a MS SQL Server 2008 db table (call it `foo` for simplicity).

This column is actually a `null` or 1 to n long list of `int`. The `int`s are actually foreign keys to another table (call it `censusblock` with a pk `id` of type of `int`), numbering from 1 to ~9600000.

I want to **query to extract the `censusblocks` list from `foo`, and use the extracted list of `int` from each row to look up the corresponding `censusblock` row.** There's a long, boring rest of the query that will be used from there, but it needs to start with the census blocks pulled from the `foo` table's `censusblocks` column.

This conversion-and-look-up is currently handled on the middle tier, with a small .NET utility class to convert from `List<int>` to `byte[]` (and vice versa), which is then written into/read from the db as `varbinary`. I would like to do the same thing, purely in SQL.

The desired query would go something along the lines of

```
SELECT f.id, c.id
FROM foo f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN censusblock c ON 
c.id IN f.censusblocks --this is where the magic happens
where f.id in (1,2)
```

Which would result in:

```
f.id   |   c.id

 1         8437314
 1         8438819
 1         8439744
 1         8441795
 1         8442741
 1         8444984
 1         8445568
 1         8445641
 1         8447953
 2         5860657
 2         5866881
 2         5866881
 2         5866858
 2         5862557
 2         5870475
 2         5868983
 2         5865207
 2         5863465
 2         5867301
 2         5864057
 2         5862256
```

*NB: the 7-digit results are coincidental. The range is, as stated above, 1-7 digits.*

The actual `censusblocks` column looks like

```
SELECT TOP 2 censusblocks FROM foo
```

which results in

```
censublocks

0x80BE4280C42380C7C080CFC380D37580DC3880DE8080DEC980E7D1
0x596D3159858159856A59749D59938B598DB7597EF7597829598725597A79597370
```

For further clarification, here's the guts of the .NET utility classes conversion methods:

```
    public static List<int> getIntegersFromBytes(byte[] data)
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        if (data != null && data.Length > 2)
        {
            long ids = data.Length / 3;
            byte[] oneId = new byte[4];
            oneId[0] = 0;
            for (long i = 0; i < ids; i++)
            {
                oneId[0] = 0;
                Array.Copy(data, i * 3, oneId, 1, 3);
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                { Array.Reverse(oneId); }
                values.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(oneId, 0));
            }}
        return values;
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromIntegers(List<int> values)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            data = new byte[values.Count * 3];
            int count = 0;
            byte[] idBytes = null;
            foreach (int id in values)
            {
                idBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(id);
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                { Array.Reverse(idBytes); }
                Array.Copy(idBytes, 1, data, count * 3, 3);
                count++;
            } }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Does the fact that "it's not your database design" mean that you can't change it?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data - expected inputs and outputs, and an example of how the data will be used once it's converted?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Yup. There should obviously be a composite table between `foo` and `censusblock` instead of this `varbinary` column, but can't make that change at the moment.

Comment: @EdHarper, for the query or for the .NET utility methods?

Comment: @Noel - For the query that you are trying to write (if I've understood correctly, this should be without reference to the .Net methods)

Comment: @EdHarper correct. I'll edit the question to add them.

Comment: @Noel - the sample data you've added shows `censusblock.id` as a zero-padded string representation of a four-digit number, not an int. Is this the actual format of the data?

Comment: @EdHarper whoops, my mistake, was doing a mental conversion when I wrote that. No zero-padding.

Comment: What does the varbinary data actually look like?

Comment: @SamDeHaan added example to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of how this might be done. It is unlikely to scale brilliantly.
If you have a numbers table in your database it should be used in place of `nums_cte`.

This works by converting the binary value to a literal hex string, then reading it in 8-character chunks

```
-- create test data
DECLARE @foo TABLE
(id int ,
 censusblocks varbinary(max)
)

DECLARE @censusblock TABLE
(id int)

INSERT @censusblock (id)
VALUES(1),(2),(1003),(5030),(5031),(2),(6)


INSERT @foo (id,censusblocks)
VALUES (1,0x0000000100000002000003EB),
(2,0x000013A6000013A7)


--query
DECLARE @biMaxLen bigint
SELECT @biMaxLen = MAX(LEN(CONVERT(varchar(max),censusblocks,2))) FROM @foo

;with nums_cte
AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@biMaxLen) ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.type) - 1) * 8) AS n
    FROM master..spt_values as a
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values as b
)
,binCTE
AS
(
    SELECT d.id, CAST(CONVERT(binary(4),SUBSTRING(s,n + 1,8),2) AS int) as cblock
    FROM (SELECT Id, CONVERT(varchar(max),censusblocks,2) AS s FROM @foo) AS d
    JOIN nums_cte
    ON n < LEN(d.s)
)
SELECT *
FROM    binCTE as b
LEFT
JOIN    @censusblock c
ON      c.id = b.cblock
ORDER BY b.id, b.cblock
```

You could also consider adding your existing .Net conversion methods into the database as an assembly and accessing them through CLR functions.

Comment: I think you got it, but I may have been overly confident as to the format of `censusblocks`, so verification of your answer has taken a left turn, but I'll report back with my results. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Sorry, I did get the desired result format incorrect. After modifying a constants `(cast(convert(binary(s/4/3)` to correct for my badly-formatted example, your query is correctly getting the first and last `cblocks` for `f.id`. But it's missing everything in-between, returning just two more rows: `12615887` and `14432384`. Is `nums_cte` skipping the intervening rows somehow?

Comment: @Noel - is this for one of the example censusblock values in your question? If so which one?

Comment: And I answer my own question.
`nums_cte`: 
`SELECT TOP (@biMaxLen) ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.type) - 1) * 3) AS n`
`binCTE`:
`SELECT d.id, CAST(CONVERT(binary(3),SUBSTRING(s,n + 1,3),2) AS int) as cblock`
gets the correct results!

Comment: yep, sorry, updated the examples above. Result was for `f.id = 1`.

Comment: @Noel - surely `nums_cte: SELECT TOP (@biMaxLen) ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.type) - 1) * 6) AS n binCTE: SELECT d.id, CAST(CONVERT(binary(3),SUBSTRING(s,n + 1,6),2) AS int) as cblock`? (6 not 3 as substring/multiplier)

Comment: Nope, the substring/mulitplier is 3. 6 would be a reasonable design decision. This db/utility design is evil. Now I have to figure out how to make it run across 9.6 million rows :(

Answer (score 1):

This is off-topic, but I couldn't resist writing these conversions so they use `IEnumerable`s instead of arrays and `List`s. This might not be faster per se, but is more general and would allow you to perform the conversion without loading the *whole* array at once, which may be helpful if the arrays you are dealing with are large.

Here it is, for what it's worth:

```
static IEnumerable<int> BytesToInts(IEnumerable<byte> bytes) {

    var buff = new byte[4];

    using (var en = bytes.GetEnumerator()) {

        while (en.MoveNext()) {

            buff[0] = en.Current;
            if (en.MoveNext()) {
                buff[1] = en.Current;
                if (en.MoveNext()) {
                    buff[2] = en.Current;
                    if (en.MoveNext()) {
                        buff[3] = en.Current;
                        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                            Array.Reverse(buff);
                        yield return BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong number of bytes.", "bytes");

        }

    }

}

static IEnumerable<byte> IntsToBytes(IEnumerable<int> ints) {

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        return ints.SelectMany(
            b => {
                var buff = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
                Array.Reverse(buff);
                return buff;
            }
        );

    return ints.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes);

}
```

Your code seems to like encoding an `int` into 3 bytes instead of 4, which would cause problems with values that don't fit into 3 bytes (including negatives) - is that intentional?

BTW, you should be able to adapt this (or your) code for execution in [SQL Server CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR). This is not exactly "in SQL", but is "in DBMS".

Comment: Nice work, though this is a legacy system (not my code! ;) that is being replaced with a much more streamlined Scala/Lift solution. However, since the DB can't be altered at the moment, I may take your advice to create a CLR assembly to keep the mess on the db side until a redesign is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can use Convert(int, censusBlock) to convert the varchar value to int value.
the you can join on that column.
Or have i misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yep, misunderstood the question. First, the column is varbinary, not varchar. Second, it's actually a list of ints, not a single int.